# how to override styles of angular material into angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular material` with `auto complete` and select and I need to override few `styles`, but I am not able to see these during inspect with my files.

**CSS:**

I tried by adding `parent class`, `::ng-deep` but nothing worked

```
  .mdc-text-field--filled .mdc-line-ripple {
      border-bottom-color: 2px solid #922269 !important;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="field-2" *ngIf="dropdownSelection != 'licenseInformation'">
    <form class="form"  [formGroup]="form">
      <mat-form-field class="width-100">
        <mat-icon matPrefix class="search-icon">search</mat-icon>
        <input matInput aria-label="State" placeholder="Enter a Name" [matAutocomplete]="auto" class="paddingleft-5 text-medium"
        (ngModelChange)="updatedVal($event)" type="text" [formControl]="stateCtrl"/>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)">
          <div *ngIf="showAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading">
              <mat-spinner diameter="50" class="show-center"></mat-spinner>
            </mat-option>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
            <mat-option class="option-custom text-medium" *ngFor="let state of filteredOptions | async"
              [value]="state" [ngClass]="{'hide-autocomplete': !showAutocomplete}">
              <span>{{state}}</span>
            </mat-option>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <mat-option *ngIf="showAutocomplete && noSearchdata.length >3" ><span class="see-results text-medium">See all
              results </span></mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
        <span class="clear-position" *ngIf="stateCtrl.value" (click)="clearValue()">CLEAR</span>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Is there anything I have missed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try

```
/* Border */
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
      border-bottom-color: 2px solid #922269 !important;
}
/* Font color */
input.mat-input-element {
      border-bottom-color: 2px solid #922269 !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but sorry didnt work

Comment: i have added image

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be overriding tags that way. Here is a quote from the docs:

> Angular Material may change component style specificity at any time, making custom overrides brittle and prone to breaking.
>
> https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#css-specificity

Instead:

> For any Angular Material component, you can safely define custom CSS for a component's host element that affect the positioning or layout of that component, such as margin, position, top, left, transform, and z-index. You should apply such styles by defining a custom CSS class and applying that class to the component's host element.
>
> https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles#component-host-elements

You also appear to be using `border-bottom-color` when you likely want to be using `border-bottom` instead, as you are defining the thickness and border style, not just the color.

Example:

```css
.my-form-field {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #922269 !important;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="my-form-field width-100">
   ...
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: thanks for response, but the border line comes out of the input, i want to overlap with that style

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or clarify a little more what you mean? If you want a border on the input you should be able to just apply a custom class the same way: `<input class="my-form-field ... />`. If you want to override the theme you can do so via scss: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#applying-a-theme-to-components